# Parsing module for Elasticsearch logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elastic-beats

There are a variety of logs generated from Elasticsearch (elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log  elasticsearch.log
elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log, etc ) . 
Is there any module in the beats world, or plugins for Logstash which can parse the logs. I dont want to write custom grok for these logs.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, there is! You simply need to enable the [`elasticsearch` module in Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-elasticsearch.html) and you'll get all the ES log files parsed for you

```
./filebeat modules enable elasticsearch
```

Then simply configure the different [file sets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-elasticsearch.html#_literal_server_literal_log_fileset_settings) you need